# How to change the meta tag images when sharing a post in social media depending on the url with jquery?

Tags: jquery, share, meta

I need to find a way to change the meta tag content images in the  tag of the HTML page depending if the url matches a certain word.

I was able to change the meta tag content images to share the articles on twitter, facebook, linkedln, etc... however it is always the same picture.

My customer wants to change the image depending of the post to share. I will need to create function with the different params to check if the url matches a certain string it changes the content in the meta tags dynamically. How can I do that with jquery? or any other suggestions are welcome!

```
    var imgSrc = $('property[og="image:url"]').attr("content");
    var currentUrl = window.location.href ;


    if(currentUrl.toLowerCase().indexOf('certain string in url') >= 0) {

        imgSrc = 'url of image';

    } else {
        imgSrc = "another url"
    };
```

Comment: Do you mean you've already got code to change the meta tags but the image isn't changing? Can we see the code you've got so far?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already change the meta tags info by changing the values in the <head> tag in the html document and I was able to change the image, title, description,etc...when sharing the post on social media. Now, what my customer wants is depending of the post to change the image in the meta tags. I edited my question to include code.

Comment: Looks like you've got a good start! But you're only changing the value of the variable `imgSrc`. Consider resetting the `content` attribute of the element.  See [.attr( attributeName, value )](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2).

Comment: Thanks man!, I have just tried that with the title meta tags(it was easy to debug and test with this attr) and it worked!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your existing code, you are setting the value of the variable `imgSrc`.
In order to update the meta tag, you'll need to reset its `content` attribute.

I recommend saving a reference to the element so that you don't need to select it again:

```js
var $metaOgImage = $('property[og="image:url"]');
var currentUrl = window.location.href;

if (currentUrl.toLowerCase().indexOf('certain string in url') >= 0) {
  $metaOgImage.attr('content', 'url of image');
} else {
  $metaOgImage.attr('content', 'another url');
};
```